# Android How to Improve my app dependencies

Tags: android

I'm trying to improve my app dependencies and came across a problem. My code base is shared with another app, so I have modules that are shared between these two apps. The below image is a simplified version of what I currently have.

[image]

Currently, my app build gradle sets the `AppNetwork` dependency as implementation and the `AppNetwork` declares the `SharedNetwork` dependency as `api`. It's api because app module needs to know stuff about the `SharedNetwork` module (more on this next). App module also implements the `SharedFuncionalities` module.

`SharedNetwork` contains an `INetwork` interface. This interface is extended by `IAppNetwork` interface that it's implemented by `AppNetworkImpl` (the latter two files are placed in the `AppNetwork` module).

Here is an example of why this is being set like this.

My app module creates `AppNetworkImpl` and also creates an `ItemRepository` (location is inside the `SharedFuncionalities` module) that takes `INetwork` (implemented by `AppNetworkImpl`) as a param in its constructor. This allows the `ItemRepository` to "talk" with the `SharedNetwork` module.

If I set `AppNetwork` to declare the `SharedNetwork` dependency as implementation thus making my app module unaware of the `SharedNetwork` (that makes sense to me. I would then use `AppNetworkImp` as the bridge between the app module and the `SharedNetwork` module) I then lose the ability to create objects in the `SharedFuncionalities` that use `AppNetworkImpl` as the bridge for using the `SharedNetwork`.

What I would like to know if I have the possibility of the app module only knowing about `AppNetwork` but still create objects in `SharedFuncionalities` that can "talk" with the `SharedNetwork`.